# Looking for a query to pull a first and last entry for a people entering site

Tags: timestamp, max, min

I looking to track people that are logging daily based on following table:

```
TimeStamp           |   PersonName  |  Location | ID
------------------- | --------------| ----------| ----
19/11/2016 07:51:06 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
19/11/2016 07:51:10 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
19/11/2016 07:51:10 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
19/11/2016 07:51:14 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
19/11/2016 07:55:12 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
19/11/2016 10:15:03 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
19/11/2016 10:30:23 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
19/11/2016 13:32:51 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
19/11/2016 13:39:51 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
19/11/2016 13:59:51 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
19/11/2016 14:32:51 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
19/11/2016 15:32:51 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
19/11/2016 15:52:51 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
19/11/2016 16:12:51 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
19/11/2016 16:32:51 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
20/11/2016 07:51:06 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
20/11/2016 07:51:10 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
20/11/2016 07:51:10 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
20/11/2016 07:51:14 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
20/11/2016 07:55:12 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
20/11/2016 10:15:03 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
20/11/2016 10:30:23 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
20/11/2016 13:32:51 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
20/11/2016 13:39:51 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
20/11/2016 13:59:51 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
20/11/2016 14:32:51 | John Brady    | Admin     | 1234
20/11/2016 15:32:51 | Alan Hartigan | Admin     | 1233
20/11/2016 15:52:51 | Kris King     | Store     | 1232
20/11/2016 16:12:51 | John Brady    | Store     | 1234
20/11/2016 16:32:51 | John Forest   | Store     | 1231
```

Based on the timestamp, I'm looking to get all people that logged in and out on `19/11/2016`.

```
First Logging       |   Last Logging      | Person Name     |  ID 
------------------- | ------------------- | ----------------|------
19/11/2016 07:51:06 | 19/11/2016 16:12:51 | John Brady      | 1234  
19/11/2016 07:51:10 | 19/11/2016 15:32:51 | Alan Hartigan   | 1233  
19/11/2016 07:51:10 | 19/11/2016 15:52:51 | Kris King       | 1232  
19/11/2016 07:51:14 | 19/11/2016 16:12:51 | John Brady      | 1234  
19/11/2016 07:55:12 | 19/11/2016 16:32:51 | John Forest     | 1231
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show, ho you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
SELECT MIN(TimeStamp) as "First Logging", MAX(TimeStamp) as "Last Logging", PersonName, ID
FROM table
WHERE DATE(TimeStamp) = "2016-11-19"
GROUP BY PersonName, ID
```

Comment: Sound! It does work just modified it slightly 

WHERE (TimeStamp) >= '10-26-2016' and (TimeStamp) <= '10-27-2016'

Cheers Julien.